# ASP.Net Core how to parse XML Request with ISO-8859-1 Charset

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, streamreader, xmldocument, iso-8859-1

I am trying to create a web API that takes XML as an input.
The problem is that the requests are encoded as ISO-8859-1.

At first I tried just using an `XmlDocument` parameter but it gave a `500` error when the encoding was wrong:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult XmlEndpoint([FromBody] XmlDocument requestXmlBody)
```

Next I tried parsing it myself but this never closed the request properly and caused HTTP Clients to be connected forever when the XML was malformed.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> XmlEndpoint()
{
    using var stringReader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, dataEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
    var body = await stringReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var requestXmlBody = new XmlDocument();
    requestXmlBody.LoadXml(body);
```

Afterwards I tried using the ASP.NET Core functionallity part-way, however this gives `Unsupported Media Type` when ISO-8599-1 is used:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> XmlEndpoint([FromBody] string content)
{
    var requestXmlBody = new XmlDocument();
    requestXmlBody.LoadXml(content);
```

This is the command I used for testing:

```sh
curl -XPOST 'https://localhost/api/XmlEndpoint' --data "<broken</broken>" -H "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=iso-8859-1"
```

How can I get an `XMLDocument` from the `ISO-8859-1` encoded request?

Comment: Why not specify `System.Text.Encoding.Latin1` in your StreamReader?  This "never closed the request properly" shouldn't happen, and you probably just had a bug in your controller.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft `System.Text.Encoding.Latin1` Doesn't exist anywhere I can find but I did find `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`. Thank you for hinting that it isn't this code but something else, I wrote an answer to what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix attempt 2. into working.
The reason I had it never closed the connection properly was because I had a custom middleware that broke because the `StreamReader` closed the stream.

So in the end the solution that worked for me is:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> WriteXmlToFile()
{
    using var stringReader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), leaveOpen: true);
    var body = await stringReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var requestXmlBody = new XmlDocument();
    requestXmlBody.LoadXml(body);
```

Thank you to @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for making me aware that it shouldn't be this code that makes the connection hang but something else.